# Range of router and device in WiFi

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11

Is range of the wifi network depend on Router only? Or does it depend on the connection device also?
I believe that the device need to transmit packet to router, so the range till which the device can reach also matters.

Comment: The range of a Wi-Fi network depends on the *wireless access point* and the client. Only with off-topic consumer-grade hardware the WAP is integrated in a "router" multi-function device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wi-fi requires two-way communication, so yes, proper operation depends on the transmit power and receiver sensitivity of both the mobile station and access point.